# DataGridView - Load large number of data very slow

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

I have a form with Datagridview that load data from db to binding source and then set binding source as `DataSource` of datagrid
I call `SuspendBinding()` and set `RaiseListChangedEvents` to false before fill data from db and when data fill call `ResumeBinding()` and `ResetBindings(false)` and set `RaiseListChangedEvents` to true

```
newPriceListSelectBindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
newPriceListSelectBindingSource.SuspendBinding();
newPriceListSelectTableAdapter.Fill(dsOrders.NewPriceListSelect, null, int.Parse(trvCategory.SelectedNode.Name), Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value));
newPriceListSelectBindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
newPriceListSelectBindingSource.ResumeBinding();
newPriceListSelectBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
```

in many windows operating systems when filling data finished, `resetbindings(false)` call immediately, but in windows server 2008 r2 this method call very very slow (it seem to program hangs).
of course I'm not sure this depends on windows.
data rows is about 80000 rows in 20 columns.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: could this be a Paging `DataGrid Paging` issue and not a binging Issue..? also what about looking at the query that returns the data.. I would also look at refactoring the code to load only a set amount of data based on a date filter then if the users need to see more data then add some filtering to your process..

Comment: @DJKRAZE why `resetbinding` is slow only on some windows?

Comment: are you asking `what or did you me WHY` take a look at this `SO` Posting it will answer your question the Marked accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145736/loading-datatable-slow-when-bound-to-datagridview-datasource I think you could truly simplify your problems if you would re think the process and do some refactoring personally..

Comment: @DJKRAZE I want to say Why

Comment: take a look at the link in my comment also I would suggest not enabling the datagrid during load until you have completed the binding..we also can't see what other events are being called while the DataGrid is being loaded..

Comment: in addition to what @DJKRAZE said on filter data, you may what to look at using server side paging.

Comment: @DJKRAZE but this is not my answer in 99 percents form load immediately after fill method but in some times it is slow.

Comment: @DJKRAZE I think that in some operating systems or on some PCs some options is different in Dot Net Framework, that with change them my problem is solved

Comment: then you need to check to make sure that all the machines are running on the same version of .net framework and I still believe that you should be pulling in lessa data and not trying to load so many records at once into a DataGrid just a thought that you should reconsider your options and think about refactoring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem
Problem was for grid column property named `DataGridViewColumn.AutoSizeMode` because the value of this property for one of column is **AllCells** and I changed this to **DisplayedCells** and problem fixed.

Comment: Finally after 3 long years! :D

Comment: No I Found the problem 2 years a go but I forgot to answer my question