# Reload DataGrid with DataSource is too slow only when DataGrid is on the current active tab

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have TabControl and DataGrid with DataSource in one of the tabs . 
When I "Reload" my DataSource (pull data from DataBase, clear DataSource and fill it again with the objects), it is too slow (a half an hour or more, for 65000 records) if current active Tab is tab where is the DataGreed. If some other Tab is active it takes 2 minutes.

I just do test with "visible=false" for DataGrid and it work fast, as normal, but it is not an option, I wanna that client see DataGreed during its reload.

It looks as the DataGrid does "something" (which slow down) after adding every single row in DataSource.

AutoSizeColumnsMode is already None

Is there any trick how I can solve this problem? any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Is using wpf an option? If thats the case, you could look into Virtualisation. Loads only what you see.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use WPF, whole application is already developed.

Comment: DataGrid will take long to load that many rows, using a different thread to fetch your data and updating the UI as the rows are fetched is an option then.

Comment: I think that problem is not to load, then to render all rows, one by one. I do not know to prevent rendering one by one. When tab with DataGrid is not currently active, everything work fine, only when DataGrid is in focus, the problem appears.

Comment: Is DataGridView an option for you? In a DataGridView you could implement virtual mode.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: It is a DataGridView. I have never used virtual mode, but as I can see, seems it is a little bit more code than I expected :). Must be something more simple here's, something to solve this graphic issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid rendering every row in DataGrid one by one, I set:

```
myDataGrid.DataSource = null;
```

After it fill my dataSource with the data, and after it back my original binding source.

```
myDataGrid.DataSource = originalBindingSource;
```

Problem here could be only that we will empty DataGrid during the reloading (because DataSource = null).
We can make another helping collection and set it as a DataSource, until originalDataSource is filling.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try to use Background Worker to fill DataGridView.
2. Also what I noticed that Telerik RadGridView loads its data dynamically when moving ScrollBar.
3. [Loading DataTable Slow When Bound to DataGridView.Datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145736/loading-datatable-slow-when-bound-to-datagridview-datasource)